# WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type EurekaServerContext when deploying Jhipster Microservices

Tags: java, jboss, jhipster, netflix-eureka

I build some WAR files from a Jhipster application and tried to deploy them on Jboss. After adding a **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** file, I managed to deploy the Gateway successfully.

Unfortunately, microservices failed with the following stacktrace :

> org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type EurekaServerContext with qualifiers @Default
>     at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [UnbackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject com.netflix.eureka.resources.SecureVIPResource(EurekaServerContext)
>     at com.netflix.eureka.resources.SecureVIPResource.(SecureVIPResource.java:0)

There are 7 other similar stacktraces on other classes : VIPResource, ASGResource, etc...

The problem is that I can't really change anything in the com.netflix.eureka package...
I've seen similar errors on the web, and one solution was to add an empty **bean.xml** file into WEB-INF.

Unfortunately, that only resulted in another error :

> javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unable to resolve a bean for 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' with qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()].
>           at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.JpaRepositoryExtension.createRepositoryBean(JpaRepositoryExtension.java:118)
>           at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.JpaRepositoryExtension.afterBeanDiscovery(JpaRepositoryExtension.java:94)

Do you know if there is a solution to this problem... or an alternative?

Note : I'm using Jboss because of... company constraints. Without these constraints, I would go for the basic standalone Tomcat execution, or Docker containers...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to exclude the weld subsystem

see: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/1303#issuecomment-87075166

I did this in my jboss-deployment-structure.xml file for a much older jhipster app:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
   <deployment>
       <exclusions>
           <module name="javaee.api" />
           <module name="org.slf4j" />
           <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
       </exclusions>
       <exclude-subsystems>
           <subsystem name="jpa" />
           <subsystem name="weld" />
       </exclude-subsystems>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Is this a JBoss Weld library config or JBoss container Weld config? as I was trying to include/exclude WELD scanning a JAVA EE specific spec like just the JPA or just the JAX-RS modules, but there is no way to do that